# Problem with recognizing modules in android

Tags: java, android, overloading

I am quite baffled with this android code I'm trying to implement. I'm getting a syntax error at return new AlertDialog.Builder(this), and it is telling me that .setMultiChoiceItems is not recognized.

Can anyone help me fix this?

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

switch(id){
case 0:
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int WhichButton){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Ok clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton){

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!": " unchecked!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    )
.create();
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `setNegativeButton()`?

Comment: What are `items` and `itemsChecked`?

Comment: Items is a string array, and Items checked is a boolean array.